# Problem with CREATE TABLE name quotation marks

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

I'm trying create table but i have an error. Here is my node.js server.
`

```
db.addWorkout = (workout) =>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        pool.query('CREATE TABLE ? (id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, exercise VARCHAR(100), sets VARCHAR(100))', [workout], (error, result)=>{
            if(error){
                return reject(error);
            }
             
              return resolve(result);
        });
    });
};
```

`

Here is error:

`

```
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''asd' (id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, exercise VARCHAR(100),...' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "CREATE TABLE 'asd' (id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, exercise VARCHAR(100), sets VARCHAR(100))"
```

`

There is a problem with quotation marks as we can see in that error msg. There is 'asd' should be just asd without quotation marks. How can I fix it?

When I try:
`pool.query('CREATE TABLE` ? `(id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, exercise VARCHAR(100), sets VARCHAR(100))'`

with `` around ? there is no error but in my database tables name are with ''.

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IraHW.png)

There is my workout variable:

```
app.post('/myplan', redirectLogin, async(req, res, next)=>{
try{ 
    const workoutName = req.body.workout;

    if(!workoutName){
        err_msg = 'err';
        return res.render('myplan.ejs', {err_msg: err_msg});
    }
    else{
            err_msg = 'err';

            user = await db.addWorkout(workoutName);
            err_msg = 'Wszystko fajnie lecimy dalej';
            return res.render('myplan.ejs', {err_msg: err_msg});     
    }
    } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
```

})

as you can see it's const from input type=text from my html file.

Comment: you can't use replacement parameters for database, table, or column names, just for data.

Comment: Should you really be dynamically creating tables for this...?

Comment: @caTS Yes, I want the user to be able to create a table in the database where his training plan will be saved. So it needs to provide a unique name that will be remembered

Comment: But you don't need a new table? You can just have one table "workouts" that stores the "unique name".

Comment: While I find your whole design a bit questionable: If you want to parameterize schema elements (table names, column names, ...) you need to use `??` instead of `?` https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-identifiers